# Python: Find word in file and folders

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, recursion

Problem:
Using recursion it should go through all folders and files and search for a specific word.
If you find a match then you should print path to file and line order is on.
Finally, print out how many folders and files you have searched through and the number of times the word has appeared in the files.

I find this problem difficult and need some help. My code contain errors, but I am not sure how to solve these problems. Two of my errors: My solution does not count the occurrence of words correct, any tips? Pressing Search results in output in terminal, not in GUI-window.

```
from tkinter import *  # Import tkinter
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
import os

def findInFile(filename, word1):
    try:
        if not os.path.isfile(filename):
            list = os.listdir(filename)              
            for i in range(len(list)):
                findInFile(list[i], word1)             
                text.insert(END, findInFile())
        else:
            findWord(filename, word1)
    except:
        print("Error")  

def findWord(filename, word1):
    try:
        infile = open(filename,"r")
        for line in infile:
            if line.find(word1)>0:
                print(filename+ ": " + line)    
    except:
        return "No words"

def processLine(filename, word1):       # count words
    wordCounts = {} # Create an empty dictionary to count words    
    for line in filename:
        pairs = list(wordCounts.items()) # Get pairs from the dictionary   
        items = [[count, word] for (word, count) in pairs] 
        items.sort(reverse = True) # Sort pairs in items
        line = replacePunctuation(line) # Replace punctuation with space
        words = line.split() # Get words from each line

    for word in words:
        if word in wordCounts:
            wordCounts[word] += 1 # Increase count for word
        else:
            wordCounts[word] = 1 # Add an item in the dictionary
            
# Replace punctuation in the line with space
def replacePunctuation(line):
    for ch in line:
        if ch in "~@#$%^&*()_-+=~<>?/,.;:!{}[]|'\"":
            line = line.replace(ch, " ")
    return line

def getNumberOfFiles(filename):
    size = 0
    if not os.path.isfile(filename):
        list = os.listdir(filename)
        for i in range(len(list)):
            size += getNumberOfFiles(filename + "\\" + list[i])
    else:
        size += 1
    return size

# def directory_contents():
# call on root/top-level folder first, then loop through those contents, 
# if a folder is found call the folder_contents on that folder, 
# if a file is found then use the search_file function to search for 
# occurrences of the word and return that number. 


# def search_file():


def showResult():
    print("\n\nSearch start.")
    print("-----------------------")
    print(findInFile(filename.get(), word1.get()))
    print("-----------------------")
    print("Search end. ")
    print("Searched: directories and", getNumberOfFiles(filename.get()), "file(s), found", processLine(filename.get(), word1.get()), "occurences of", word1.get())

def openFile():
    filenameforReading = askopenfilename()
    filename.set(filenameforReading)

window = Tk()  # Create a window
window.title("Find word in files")  # Set title

frame1 = Frame(window)  # Hold four labels for displaying cards
frame1.pack()

Label(frame1, text="Filename or directory: ").pack(side=LEFT)
filename = StringVar()
Entry(frame1, width=20, textvariable=filename).pack(side=LEFT)
Button(frame1, text="Browse", command=openFile).pack(side=LEFT)
Label(frame1, text="Enter a word ").pack(side=LEFT)
word1 = StringVar()
Entry(frame1, width=20, textvariable=word1).pack(side=LEFT)
Button(frame1, text="Search", command=showResult).pack(side=LEFT)

frame2 = Frame(window)  
frame2.pack()

text = Text(frame2, width=100, height=30)
text.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: `print` outputs to STDOUT, not to your GUI. You need to specify a widget you want to "print" the text to and configure/insert text, depending on what widget you use

Answer (score 0):

```
def findWord(filename, word1):
    try:
        infile = open(filename,"r")
        data=infile.read()
        line=data.count(word1)
        #for line in infile:
        #   if line.find(word1)>0:
        line=str(line)
        return filename+ ": " + line    
    except:
        return "No words"

def showResult():
    print("\n\nSearch start.")
    print("-----------------------")
    print(findWord(filename.get(), word1.get()))
    print("-----------------------")
    print("Search end. ")
    print("Searched: directories and", getNumberOfFiles(filename.get()), "file(s), found", processLine(filename.get(), word1.get()), "occurences of", word1.get())
```